# Use list of words saved in text file to search for string - powershell

Tags: shell, powershell, text-files

I've got a script that searches for a string ("End program" in this case). It then goes through each file within the folder and outputs any files not containing the string.

It works perfectly when the phrase is hard coded, but I want to make it more dynamic by creating a text file to hold the string. In the future, I want to be able to add to the list of string in the text file. I can't find this online anywhere, so any help is appreciated.

Current code:

```
$Folder = "\\test path"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Folder -Filter "*.log"| ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-31)} 

#String to search for within the file
$SearchTerm = "*End program*"

ForEach( $File in $Files)
{
    $Text = Get-Content "$Folder\$File" | select -Last 1

    If ($Text | WHERE {$Text -inotlike $SearchTerm} )
    {  
        $Arr += $File                         
    }
}
if($Arr.Count -eq 0)
{
    break
}
```

This is a simplified version of the code displaying only the problematic area. I'd like to put "End program" and another string "End" in a text file.

The following is what the contents of the file look like:

```
*End program*, *Start*
```

Comment: You mean like a comma separated list?

Comment: @Hackerman yes I've  edited the question to reflect that

Comment: Use `Import-Csv`, check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3733217/parsing-a-comma-separated-file-using-powershell